# how to find column in table using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

how to find other column in table using laravel. By using the `find($id)` i believe that this is for the id in the table. I want to find the `lead_id` column in table. How will i able to do that? Here is my code below

```
$recent = RecentlyViewed::findLeadId($leadId);
                $status = "Close/Converted";

                $recent->flag_status = $status;
                $recent->save();
```

in my model

```
class RecentlyViewed extends Model
{

    public static function findLeadId($leadId)
    {
        return static::where('lead_id', $leadId)->first();
    }

    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'lead_id',
        'client_id',
        'status',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'date',
        'flag_status',
    ];

}
```

it wont work to get the lead_id in my table recently viewed table. Any help is muchly appreciated. TIA

Comment: What does "it won't work" mean? Do you get an error of some sort?

Comment: change `static` to `self`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `protected $primaryKey = "lead_id";` in model. If primaryKey significant other impacts. The do with Laravel query builder.
 Don't forget to add `use DB;`.

```
DB::table('RecentlyViewed')
                ->where('lead_id', $leadId)
                ->update(['flag_status' => "Close/Converted"]);
```

Comment: Using `DB::table` skips Eloquent, which may have significant side effects (especially if you use scopes, events etc.). Changing the primary key will also have major impacts, especially if `id` and `lead_id` are used for different purposes.

Comment: so what is the best way for this?

Comment: @PHPDev You could answer my comments above, where I asked two questions - what does "it won't work" mean and what error do you get. You could also try Afraz Ahmad's suggestion.